# Undefined Method 'class_builder' for Create::Class, no changes to code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trailblazer

I was following along the Trailblazer book to learn me some Trailblazer. Yesterday, all my tests were green. Today, I tried to add the `rails-timeago` helper today, which I had a little bit of troubles with, but I ultimately managed to fix. After I got the gem working, I re-ran my existing tests, and, to my surprise, all were red, and the existing operations were to blame.

I opened a rails console to test my operations, so I did a `Create.`, and it indeed failed there. I'm running out of ideas and Google hasn't been helping me particularly.

This is the error code (on rails console):

```
irb(main):004:0> Thing::Create.(thing: {name: 'Rails', description: 'Kiackass web app'})
#: undefined method `class_builder' for Thing::Create:Class
Did you mean?  class_attribute
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/trailblazer-1.1.1/lib/trailblazer/operation/builder.rb:20:in `build_operation_class'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/trailblazer-1.1.1/lib/trailblazer/operation/builder.rb:24:in `build_operation'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/trailblazer-1.1.1/lib/trailblazer/operation.rb:34:in `call'
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `'
```

This is my current gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

gem "sass-rails"
gem "uglifier"
gem "coffee-rails"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "foundation-rails"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "simple_form"
gem "therubyracer", :platform=>:ruby
gem "thin"
gem "sqlite3"

group :development do
  gem "binding_of_caller", :platforms=>[:mri_21]
  gem "rails_layout"
end

gem "responders"

group :development, :test do
  gem "minitest-rails-capybara"
  gem "minitest-line"
  gem "minitest-reporters"
  gem "win32console"
end

group :test do
  gem 'memory_test_fix'
end

group :production do
  gem "rails_12factor"
end

gem "reform"
# gem "reform", github: "apotonick/reform", branch: "reform-2"
#gem "reform", path: "../reform"

# gem "representable", path: "../representable"
gem "representable"
# gem "reform", "2.0.4"
# gem "disposable", github: "apotonick/disposable"
gem "virtus"

# gem "disposable", path: "../disposable"
gem "tyrant"
# gem "tyrant", path: "../tyrant"

gem "trailblazer"
gem "trailblazer-loader"
gem "trailblazer-rails"
# gem "trailblazer", path: "../trailblazer"
# gem "trailblazer-loader", path: "../trailblazer-loader"
# gem "trailblazer-rails", path: "../trailblazer-rails"

# gem "disposable", path: "../disposable"
# gem "trailblazer-rails", ">= 0.1.3"
# gem "cells", git: "https://github.com/apotonick/cells"
# gem "cells", path: "../cells"
gem "cells"
gem "cells-haml"
gem "haml", github: "haml/haml", ref: "7c7c169"
gem "kaminari-cells"

gem "paperdragon"
gem "file_validators"
# gem "roar", path: "../roar" #"1.0.0"
gem "roar"

gem "pundit"

gem "rails-timeago"
gem "email_validator"

gem "foundation-icons-sass-rails"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

This is the operator's code:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  class Create < Trailblazer::Operation
    include Model

    model Thing, :create

    contract do
      property :name
      property :description

      validates :name, presence: true
      validates :description, length: {in: 4..160}, allow_blank: true
    end

    def process(params)
      validate(params[:thing]) do |f|
        f.save
      end
    end
  end

  class Update < Create
    action :update

    contract do
      property :name, writeable: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is the code for some of my tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ThingCrudTest < Minitest::Spec
  describe "Create" do
    it "persists valid" do
      thing = Thing::Create.(thing: {name: 'Rails', description: 'Kickass web dev'}).model

      thing.persisted?.must_equal true
      thing.name.must_equal 'Rails'
      thing.description.must_equal "Kickass web dev"
    end

    it "invalid name" do
      res, op = Thing::Create.run(thing: {name: ""})

      res.must_equal false
      op.model.persisted?.must_equal false
      op.contract.errors.to_s.must_equal "{:name=>[\"can't be blank\"]}"
    end

    it "invalid description" do
      res, op = Thing::Create.run(thing: {name: "Rails", description: "hi"})

      res.must_equal false
      op.contract.errors.to_s.must_equal"{:description=>[\"is too short (minimum is 4 characters)\"]}"
    end
  end

  describe "Update" do
    let (:thing) do
      Thing::Create.(thing: {name: "Rails", description: "Kickass web dev"}).model
    end

    it "persists valid, ignores name" do
      new_thing = Thing::Update.(id: thing.id, thing: {name: "Rails", description: "Simply better"}).model

      new_thing.name.must_equal "Rails"
      new_thing.description.must_equal "Simply better"
    end
  end
end
```

This is the tests' output:

```
Started with run options --seed 46307

ERROR["test_0002_invalid name", #, 0.00465575500857085]?
 test_0002_invalid name#Create (0.01s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `class_builder' for Thing::Create:Class
        Did you mean?  class_attribute
            test/concepts/thing/crud_test.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in '

ERROR["test_0001_persists valid", #, 0.0119611140107736]
 test_0001_persists valid#Create (0.01s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `class_builder' for Thing::Create:Class
        Did you mean?  class_attribute
            test/concepts/thing/crud_test.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in '

ERROR["test_0003_invalid description", #, 0.019230154925026]
 test_0003_invalid description#Create (0.02s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `class_builder' for Thing::Create:Class
        Did you mean?  class_attribute
            test/concepts/thing/crud_test.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in '

ERROR["test_0001_persists valid, ignores name", #, 0.031214163987897336]
 test_0001_persists valid, ignores name#Update (0.03s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `class_builder' for Thing::Create:Class
        Did you mean?  class_attribute
            test/concepts/thing/crud_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in '
            test/concepts/thing/crud_test.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in '

ERROR["test_0001_allows anonymous", ThingIntegrationTest, 0.06196290999650955]
 test_0001_allows anonymous#ThingIntegrationTest (0.06s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `class_builder' for Thing::Create:Class
        Did you mean?  class_attribute
            app/controllers/things_controller.rb:3:in `new'
            test/integration/thing_test.rb:5:in `block in '

  5/5: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.07067s
5 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 5 errors, 0 skips
```

This is a runthrough of `gem list` for reference.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.0.0.1)
actionmailer (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
actionpack (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
actionview (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
activejob (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
activemodel (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
activerecord (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
activesupport (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1, 4.2.4)
acts_as_commentable (4.0.2)
addressable (2.5.0)
ansi (1.5.0)
arel (7.1.4, 7.1.3, 6.0.3)
ast (2.3.0)
autoprefixer-rails (6.5.3, 6.5.0.2, 6.4.0.3)
aws-sdk-core (2.6.6)
axiom-types (0.1.1)
babel-source (5.8.35)
babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
bcrypt (3.1.11 ruby x64-mingw32, 3.1.7 x64-mingw32)
better_errors (2.1.1)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bootstrap-form (3.0.0)
bootstrap-glyphicons (0.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
bootstrap_form (2.5.2)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.13.6, 1.13.2)
byebug (9.0.6, 8.2.1)
capybara (2.11.0, 2.10.2, 2.10.1)
cells (4.1.5, 4.1.4, 4.1.3)
cells-haml (0.0.10)
cells-rails (0.0.6)
city-state (0.0.13)
coderay (1.1.1)
coercible (1.0.0)
coffee-rails (4.2.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.11.1, 1.10.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2, 1.0.0)
daemons (1.2.4)
database_cleaner (1.5.3, 1.5.2)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
declarative (0.0.8)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
disposable (0.3.2)
docile (1.1.5)
dotenv (2.1.1)
dragonfly (1.0.12)
dry-configurable (0.3.0)
dry-container (0.5.0)
dry-core (0.2.1)
dry-equalizer (0.2.0)
dry-logic (0.4.0)
dry-types (0.9.2)
dry-validation (0.10.3)
email_validator (1.6.0)
equalizer (0.0.11)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.2.1 x64-mingw32)
execjs (2.7.0, 2.6.0)
faker (1.4.2)
ffi (1.9.14 x64-mingw32)
file_validators (2.1.0)
formatador (0.2.5)
foundation-icons-sass-rails (3.0.0)
foundation-rails (6.2.4.0)
globalid (0.3.7)
glyphicons-rails (0.1.2)
guard (2.13.0)
guard-compat (1.2.1)
guard-minitest (2.4.4)
haml (4.0.7)
haml-lint (0.999.999)
haml-rails (0.9.0)
haml_lint (0.18.4)
hanami (0.9.1)
hanami-assets (0.4.0)
hanami-controller (0.8.0)
hanami-helpers (0.5.0)
hanami-mailer (0.4.0)
hanami-model (0.7.0)
hanami-router (0.8.1)
hanami-utils (0.9.1)
hanami-validations (0.7.1)
hanami-view (0.8.0)
hoe (3.15.2)
hoe-bundler (1.3.0)
hpricot (0.8.6)
html2haml (1.0.1)
http_router (0.11.2)
httparty (0.13.7)
i18n (0.7.0)
ice_nine (0.11.2)
inflecto (0.0.2)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
jbuilder (2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.4.1)
jmespath (1.3.1, 1.2.4)
jquery-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1)
json (default: 1.8.3)
json_pure (1.8.3)
kaminari (0.17.0)
kaminari-cells (0.0.4)
listen (3.0.8)
loofah (2.0.3)
lumberjack (1.0.10)
mail (2.6.4, 2.6.3)
memory_test_fix (1.4.0, 1.3.0)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1, 2.99)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
minitest (5.10.1, 5.9.1, 5.8.4, 5.8.3)
minitest-capybara (0.8.2)
minitest-line (0.6.3)
minitest-metadata (0.6.0)
minitest-rails (3.0.0, 2.2.1)
minitest-rails-capybara (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
minitest-reporters (1.1.13, 1.1.12, 1.1.9)
minitest-spec-rails (5.4.0)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
mysql2 (0.4.4 x64-mingw32, 0.4.2 x64-mingw32)
nenv (0.3.0)
nested_form (0.3.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (1.2.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8.1 x64-mingw32)
notiffany (0.1.1)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperdragon (0.0.11)
parser (2.3.3.1)
pg (0.19.0 x64-mingw32, 0.17.1 x64-mingw32)
power_assert (0.2.6)
powerpack (0.1.1)
pry (0.10.4)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
public_suffix (2.0.4)
puma (3.6.2, 3.6.0, 3.4.0)
pundit (1.1.0)
quiet_assets (1.1.0)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.5, 1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
rails-assets-datatables.net (1.10.12, 1.10.10)
rails-assets-jquery (3.1.1, 2.2.0)
rails-controller-testing (0.1.1)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.1, 1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-timeago (2.15.0)
rails_12factor (0.0.3, 0.0.2)
rails_layout (1.0.34)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5, 0.0.4)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5, 0.0.4)
railties (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
rainbow (2.1.0)
rake (12.0.0, 11.3.0, 10.5.0, 10.4.2)
rake-compiler (0.9.9)
rake-compiler-dock (0.5.3)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.2.1)
reform (2.2.3, 2.2.2)
reform-rails (0.1.7)
representable (3.0.2, 3.0.1)
responders (2.3.0)
roar (0.12.7)
rom (2.0.2)
rom-mapper (0.4.0)
rom-repository (0.3.1)
rom-sql (0.9.0)
rom-support (2.0.0)
rubocop (0.46.0)
ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
ruby_parser (3.1.3)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
sass (3.4.22, 3.4.21)
sass-rails (5.0.6)
sdoc (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
sequel (4.40.0)
sexp_processor (4.7.0)
shellany (0.0.1)
shotgun (0.9.2)
simple_form (3.3.1)
simplecov (0.12.0, 0.11.1)
simplecov-html (0.10.0)
slop (3.6.0)
spring (1.7.2, 1.6.2)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
sprockets (3.7.0, 3.5.2)
sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.12 x64-mingw32, 1.3.11 x64-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
sysexits (1.2.0)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thin (1.7.0)
thor (0.19.4, 0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.5, 2.0.2)
timeago-rails (0.1.5)
trailblazer (1.1.2, 1.1.1)
trailblazer-loader (0.1.0)
trailblazer-rails (0.4.0)
transproc (0.4.1)
turbolinks (5.0.1)
turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
tyrant (0.0.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2016.10, 1.2016.9, 1.2016.8, 1.2016.7)
uber (0.1.0, 0.0.15)
uglifier (3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.0, 2.7.2)
unicode-display_width (1.1.1)
url_mount (0.2.1)
virtus (1.0.5)
warden (1.2.6)
web-console (3.4.0, 3.3.1, 3.1.1)
websocket-driver (0.6.4)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
will_paginate (3.0.7)
win32console (1.3.2)
wisper (1.6.1)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

I am sure I haven't touched the operator's code or anything that could break it since yesterday; I was currently working on a cell. I've run `bundle install` and `bundle update` several times by now. Again, since all this was working as intended yesterday, I am willing to blame some gem shenanigans, but still any help that I could get would be much appreciated.